# How do i change the value of progressbar from minutes?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm doing a "shutdowner" project in WinForm.
I can enter there a amount of minutes, after these minutes the pc shutdown.
Now i create a progressbar, min Value of 0, Max Value of 100.

e.g:
I enter 3 minutes (180 sec), and click on a "start" button, the value should be 0, and it should be 100 when the PC shutdowns (after the entered minutes).

I tried some math, but i didn't got it to work.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: Can you show us some of the code you have tried.

Comment: Why not just set the max value to the number of seconds? Saves you having to do any maths.

Comment: Did you have a look at the ProgressBar documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Show us your math. This is a ridiculously easy problem that can be solved by simple division.

Comment: @RyanSchlueter i deleted the codes, because there weren't working
HandbagCrab because i want 100% ;)

Comment: (max seconds / 100) * current second = current percentage. This is simple maths.

Comment: @HandbagCrab so i should:
replace the max seconds to the seconds, the user have entered, and current seconds, how long the timer runs?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: You'll want to spend more time on future posts and show more research effort to get more help than downvotes

Answer (score -1):

Try something like...

```
    private int totalSeconds;
    private DateTime targetTime;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int mins = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        if (mins > 0)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mins);
            targetTime = DateTime.Now.Add(ts);
            totalSeconds = (int)ts.TotalSeconds;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            button1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = targetTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        if (ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
        {
            label1.Text = "-" + ts.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
            double percent = ((double)totalSeconds - ts.TotalSeconds) / (double)totalSeconds;
            progressBar1.Value = (int)(progressBar1.Maximum * percent);
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;

            // ... do something here! ...

        }
    }
```